# Prove that : $x^4 - y^3x + x^3y + y^4 >0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

I need a bit of help since I've been stuck on this one :

> Prove that : $x^4 - y^3x  + x^3y + y^4 >0$

It definitely holds, since I gave it a go on ***Wolfram Alpha*** : [WA Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%20%20-y%5E3x%20%2B%20x%5E3y%20%2B%20y%5E4%20%3E%200)

I can't seem how to proceed on proving this one though.

Comment: No cases needed:
$$2|xy|\leqslant x^2+y^2$$ hence $$2(x^4 - y^3x  + x^3y + y^4)\geqslant 2x^4-y^2(x^2+y^2)-x^2(x^2+y^2)+2y^4=(x^2-y^2)^2$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean that $xy\neq0.$

Let $x=ty$.

Thus, we need to prove trhat
$$t^4+t^3-t+1>0,$$
which is true for $t\geq1$ because
$$t^4+t^3-t+1=t(t^2-1)+t^4+1>0$$ and for $0\leq t<1$ because
$$t^4+t^3-t+1=t^4+t^3+1-t>0$$ and for $t<0$ because
$$t^4+t^3-t+1=t^4\left(\frac{1}{(-t)^4}+\frac{1}{(-t)^3}-\frac{1}{-t}+1\right)>0.$$

Comment: Nice and fast solution ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Also works for most cases of $xy=0$. Just not $x=y=0$.

Comment: Yes  alex of course! If $xy=0$ and $y\neq0$ or $x\neq0$ the inequality is obvious.

Comment: Ιt's $$t^4+t^3-t+1>0$$

Comment: @Paris K. Patsogiannis Thank you! I fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer Charalampos commented about was actually incorrect, I see, Michael.  It is good that you corrected what was an accepted incorrect answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$x^4-y^3x+x^3y+y^4 = x(x^3-y^3)+y(x^3+y^3) = x(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)+y(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$$, divide into three cases: $x>y>0 , 0>x>y, x>0>y$, and use the fact that $x^2+y^2\ge 2xy$.